# Access a model method from a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, class, model

I am relatively new to rails and am trying to figure this out the right syntax for the following

I have a model Transactions with the method

```
 def self.add_external_transaction_for information
...
end
```

declared in transaction.rb

What I am trying to do is call add_external_transaction_for from a different controller named DepositsController for the Deposit model like this in deposits_controller.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Transactions.add_external_transaction_for(@deposit)
```

however i see the following error

```
undefined method `add_external_transaction_for' for ActiveRecord::Transactions:Module
```

Can someone please help me. I need to be able to have a method that is associated with the Transaction model that is accessed from a controller without me having to create a new instance of Transaction just to access that method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your transaction model starts like this:

`class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base`

Then `Transaction.add_external_transaction_for(@deposit)` should work fine, it shouldn't need to be scoped to the ActiveRecord module. Also, you might be seeing a naming conflict with the ActiveRecord::Transactions module.